Nested flatlist Problem - Render inside Render
Here the problem is: I can scroll in top header and toplist but I cannot scroll by touching tab bar area.  I think this is for render inside another render, like here Sticky component is a custom flatlist component and I am providing tab bar which has a flatlist to which means I have now render inside another render and now this is creating conflicts.
 

import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabView, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import CustomFlatList from '../components/CustomFlatList/CustomFlatList';


const data = Array(10).fill(1); // Dummy data for flatlist
const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get('window').width };

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [routes] = useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
    { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
    { key: 'third', title: 'Third' },
  ]);

  const renderScene = useCallback(({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case 'first':
        return (
          <View style={styles.scene}>
            <Text>First Tab Content</Text>
          </View>
        );
      case 'second':
        return (
          <View style={styles.scene}>
            <Text>Second Tab Content</Text>
          </View>
        );
      case 'third':
        return (
          <View style={styles.scene}>
            <Text>Third Tab Content</Text>
          </View>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }, []);

  const renderTabBar = useCallback((props) => (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
      style={styles.tabBar}
    />
  ), []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <CustomFlatList
        data={data}
        style={styles.list}
        renderItem={() => <View style={styles.item} />} // Render each list item
        HeaderComponent={<View style={styles.header} />} // Top header
        TopListElementComponent={<View style={styles.topList} />} // Top element
        StickyElementComponent={(
          
      
         
          <TabView
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            initialLayout={initialLayout}
          />
      
   
         
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  list: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  header: {
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: '#ffcccc',
  },
  topList: {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#ccccff',
  },
  tabBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#673ab7',
  },
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height:44,
  },
});   ```

